# Capybara testing: Errno::ETIMEDOUT Operation timed out - connect(2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

During the execution got the following error, anyone else has encoutered the following issue?

```
Stopped due to exception:

Errno::ETIMEDOUT Operation timed out - connect(2)

/Users/dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize'
/Users/dan/Documents/Working Directory/One-Big-Switch-Website/spec/requests/admin/role_editing_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in '
```

My tests:

```
it "as a super admin I can add roles to users" do
    visit admin_dashboard_index_path ----- line 10
    login_admin_user(super_admin)
    visit admin_users_path

    page.should have_css("h2", :text => "Users")
    page.within("tr", :text => user.email) do
      click_link "Update"
    end
    page.should have_field("user_password")
  end
```

Comment: I have similar issue, still searching for solution.